# Android Studio How can I put this activity in extends Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am facing error at `setContentView`, `findViewById` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`. This code was working fine when it was extending `AppCompatActivity` but when I try to change it into a fragment it gives the error. I need to convert this code of an Activity into a fragment so that I can use it in `navigationDrawer`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class PerdidosActivity extends Fragment {

    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perdidos);
        // get the reference of FrameLayout and TabLayout
        simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        // Create a new Tab named "First"
        TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        firstTab.setText("First"); // set the Text for the first Tab
        firstTab.setIcon(R.drawable.android_icon); // set an icon for the
        // first tab
        tabLayout.addTab(firstTab); // add  the tab at in the TabLayout
        // Create a new Tab named "Second"
        TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        secondTab.setText("Second"); // set the Text for the second Tab
        secondTab.setIcon(R.drawable.android_icon); // set an icon for the second tab
        tabLayout.addTab(secondTab); // add  the tab  in the TabLayout



        // perform setOnTabSelectedListener event on TabLayout
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new FirstFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new SecondFragment();
                        break;

                }
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setContentView()**

In an Activity, you create your UI by overriding `onCreate()` and calling `setContentView()`. In a Fragment, you do it differently. Instead of overriding `onCreate()`, override `onCreateView()` and then write something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    ...
    return root;
}
```

**findViewById()**

In an Activity, you can simply call `findViewById()` anywhere, and it will search for views inside the layout you sent to `setContentView()`. In a Fragment, you need a `View` instance to call `findViewById()` on.

Inside `onCreateView()`, you can just call `root.findViewById(R.id.my_view)`. In other methods, as long as you've already returned something from `onCreateView()`, you can write `getView().findViewById(R.id.my_view)`.

**getSupportFragmentManager()**

This one's easy: just use `getFragmentManager()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will be `public class PerdidosActivity extends AppCompatActivity` and your errors will be gone. 
Explaination: You are extending an activity where you are about to use TabLayout and the views that you are gonna hook up to the TabLayout using the adapter will be fragments not the PerdidosActivity.

Comment: thx but i need to be extends Fragment because this has to be inside my navigation-drawen done with fragments, otherwise doesn't work